# Unable to remove spacing at bottom in uicollection view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a screen on which i am showing the `UICollectionView`.When i run my app it shows the blank space at bottom i don't why this is happening.I have added this code as well.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    if (collectionView==self.album_collection_view)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);
    }// top, left, bottom, right

    else
        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);

}
```

but in this way it does not work.I have also tried to resolve this through storyboard but it still does not work.

In storybpard i have tried section insects as 0 for all the directions.

Comment: check if there is any bottom bar included or debug view hierarchy

Comment: please add a screenshot of your collection view and blank space at bottom

Comment: Attach screen (from storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting UIViewController's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property to `NO`. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets):

> Discussion:
>
> The default value of this property is `YES`, which allows the view
>   controller to adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen
>   areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab
>   bar. Set to `NO` if you want to manage scroll view inset adjustments
>   yourself, such as when there is more than one scroll view in the view
>   hierarchy.

So set it like `[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];`. And then set collection view's `contentInset` property to fit your needs.

Comment: no it's not working can you please post an example code for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok. But seeing your code i don't understand why you are using condition if you are giving same UIEdgeInsets in both if and else.

May this will help you.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewlayout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayoutinsetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

if (collectionView == self.album_collection_view)
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,10);
}

else{

   return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);

  }
}
```